# Energy estimate in Evans PDE for coercivity.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

For some constant $\theta>0$ we have 
$$\frac{\theta}{2}\int_U |Du|^2 dx\le B[u,u]+C\int_U u^2dx$$ for some appropriate constant $C$. In addition we recall from Poincare's inequality that 
$$||u||_2\le C'||Du||_2$$
It easily follows that 
$$\beta ||u||_{H_0^1(U)}^2\le B[u,u]+\gamma||u||_{L^2(U)}^2$$
for appropriate constants $\beta>0,\gamma\ge 0$.

$$B[u,v]:=\int_U \sum_{i,j=1}^n a^{ij}u_{x_i}v_{x_j}+\sum_{i=1}^n b^i u_{x_i}v+cuv\, dx$$

This is the final part of the proof for the energy estimate in Evans PDE text, page 318-319. However, I don't see how to get the final inequality using Poincare's inequality. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you state what is $B[u,u]$ or the page on Evans text.

Comment: The final inequality does not use Poincare's inequality. It uses the two inequalities that you stated before. Simply because the $H^1_0$ norm is the sum of the $L^2$ norm of the function itself and of the derivative

Comment: @Bananach Yes but it says in the text that it easily follows from Poincare's inequality so I think he used it somehow.

Comment: the second inequality is Poincare's inequality

Comment: @Bananach Yes so I think Evans means we get the third from the first using Poincare, which is the second.

Comment: Poincare's inequality is used to show that $\|u\|_{H_0^1}$ is equivalent to $\|Du\|_{L^2}$. The desired inequality then follows from the first equation you stated since the LHS is $\frac{\theta}{2}\|Du\|_{L^2(U)}^2$.

Comment: I think what he says is: From (1) (which I assume was proven before) and (2) it follows that (3) holds

Comment: Btw, you can get the last inequality by adding $\frac{\theta}{2}\|u\|_{L^2(U)}^2$ to both sides of the first inequality and then you get it with $\beta=\theta/2$ and $\gamma=\max\{C,\beta\}$

Answer (score 2):

For an example of how Poincaré's inequality ($\int_U|Du|^2 \ge c\int_U|u|^2$) is being applied:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\theta}{2}\int_U|Du|^2 &= \frac{\theta}{4}\int_U|Du|^2 + \color{blue}{\frac{\theta}{4}\int_U|Du|^2} \\
&\ge \frac{\theta}{4}\int_U|Du|^2 + \color{blue}{\frac{c\theta}{4}\int_U|u|^2}\\
&\ge \beta\|u\|_{H_0^1(U)}^2,
\end{align*}
where $\beta$ depends on $\theta,c$.